# Is it the right way to create custom view with observable collection binding

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, observablecollection

In need to create a custom view and attach it to a view-model which provides two observable collections and functions to build the collections.
The collections content are shown in spinbox and colorpick controls.
My code is now working but I am not sure it is the right way to implement the binding.

the observablecollections are bound via DependencyProperty but I have seen people mentioning use of INotifyCollectionChanged and ICollectionView but could not understand how they would get individual items of the collection.

```
public partial class BinsColorControl : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
public ObservableCollection<Color> BinsColors
{
        get { return (ObservableCollection<Color>)GetValue(BinsColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BinsColorProperty, value); }
}

public ObservableCollection<double> BinsValues
{
        get { return (ObservableCollection<double>)GetValue(BinsValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BinsValueProperty, value); }
}


public static readonly DependencyProperty BinsColorProperty =
      DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("BinsColors", typeof(ObservableCollection<Color>),
         typeof(BinsColorControl),
         new UIPropertyMetadata(null, OnBinsColorCollectionChanged));

public static readonly DependencyProperty BinsValueProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register("BinsValues", typeof(ObservableCollection<double>),
         typeof(BinsColorControl),
         new UIPropertyMetadata(null, OnBinsValueCollectionChanged));

private static void OnBinsColorCollectionChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    BinsColorControl binsColorControl = d as BinsColorControl;

    var action = new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(
            (o, args) =>
            {
                if (binsColorControl != null)
                {
                    binsColorControl._reloadUI();
                }
            }
            );


    if (binsColorControl  != null)
    {
        if (e.OldValue != null)
        {
                var coll = (INotifyCollectionChanged)e.OldValue;
                // Unsubscribe from CollectionChanged on the old collection
                coll.CollectionChanged -= action;
        }

        if (e.NewValue != null)
        {
                var coll = (ObservableCollection<Color>) e.NewValue;
                // Subscribe to CollectionChanged on the new collection
                coll.CollectionChanged += action;
                binsColorControl._reloadUI();
        }
        binsColorControl.OnPropertyChanged("NOBins");
     }
 }

 private static void OnBinsValueCollectionChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        BinsColorControl binsColorControl = d as BinsColorControl;

        var action = new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(
           (o, args) =>
           {
               if (binsColorControl != null)
               {
                   binsColorControl._reloadUI();
               }
           }
           );

        if (binsColorControl != null)
        {
            if (e.OldValue != null)
            {
                var coll = (INotifyCollectionChanged)e.OldValue;
                coll.CollectionChanged -= action;
            }

            if (e.NewValue != null)
            {
                var coll = (ObservableCollection<double>)e.NewValue;
                // Subscribe to CollectionChanged on the new collection
                coll.CollectionChanged += action;
                binsColorControl._reloadUI();
            }
        }

    }
    private void _reloadUI()
    {
        ....
    }
 }
```

the realoadUI method will refresh or add controls, I might change that for better clarity :

```
 private void _reloadUI()
 {
      if (BinsColors == null || BinsValues == null)
            return;

        #region colorPickers
        while (_colorPickers.Count > NOBins)
        {
            binStack.Children.Remove(_colorPickers.Last());
            _colorPickers.Remove(_colorPickers.Last());
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < NOBins; i++)
        {
            ColorPicker colPick;
            if (i < _colorPickers.Count)
            {
                colPick = _colorPickers[i];
            }
            else
            {
                colPick = new ColorPicker();
                colPick.Margin = new Thickness(5);
                _colorPickers.Add(colPick);
            }
            colPick.SelectedColorChanged -= _onBinsColorChanged;
            colPick.SelectedColor = BinsColors.ElementAt(i);
            colPick.SelectedColorChanged += _onBinsColorChanged;
        }

        #endregion colorPickers

        #region valuePickers
        while (_valuePickers.Count > 0 && _valuePickers.Count > NOBinsValues)
        {
            binStack.Children.Remove(_valuePickers.Last());
            _valuePickers.Remove(_valuePickers.Last());
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < NOBinsValues; i++)
        {
            DoubleUpDown valPick;
            if (i < _valuePickers.Count)
            {
                valPick = _valuePickers[i];
            }
            else
            {
                valPick = new DoubleUpDown();
                valPick.Margin = new Thickness(5);
                _valuePickers.Add(valPick);
            }
            valPick.ValueChanged -= _onBinsValueChanged;
            valPick.Value = BinsValues.ElementAt(i);
            valPick.ValueChanged += _onBinsValueChanged;
        }
        #endregion valuePickers

        if (NOBins > 0)
        {
            binStack.Children.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < NOBins - 1; i++)
            {

                binStack.Children.Add(_colorPickers[i]);
                if(NOBinsValues > i)
                    binStack.Children.Add(_valuePickers[i]);
            }
            if (_colorPickers.Count == NOBins)
            {
                 binStack.Children.Add(_colorPickers[NOBins - 1]);
            }
        }
 }
```

the viewmodel used with this is called analysisViewModel :

```
public class analysisViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler CollectionsChanged;        

    public ObservableCollection<double> BinsValues { get; private set; }

    private void BinsValues_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        CollectionsChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(BinsValues)));
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Color> BinsColors { get; private set; }

    private void BinsColors_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        CollectionsChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(BinsColors)));
    }

    ....

    public ColorBinsViewModel()
    {
        BinsValues = new ObservableCollection<double>();
        BinsValues.CollectionChanged += BinsValues_CollectionChanged;
        BinsColors = new ObservableCollection<Color>();
        BinsColors.CollectionChanged += BinsColors_CollectionChanged;
        NOBins = 2;
        ...
    }

    public int NOBins
    {
        get
        {
            return BinsColors.Count;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value >= 0 && value < 25)
            {
                if (BinsColors.Count > value)
                {
                    while (value < BinsColors.Count)
                    {
                        BinsColors.RemoveAt(BinsColors.Count - 1);
                        BinsValues.RemoveAt(BinsValues.Count - 1);
                    }
                    if (BinsColors.Count < value)
                    {
                        while (BinsColors.Count < value - 1)
                        {
                            BinsColors.Add(new Color());
                            BinsValues.Add(new double());
                            BinsValues[BinsValues.Count - 1] = 0.0;
                        }
                        BinsColors.Add(new Color());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The custom view is currently used inside a grid that I use to create tabs.
This content view use the viewmodel and the custom view, which are connected via code behind, I use the viewmodel for the visualisation part of the ui so rapid factorization was not possible.
Binding between the customView  is performed by setting the datacontext in the grid constructor as follow:

```
public partial class MapAnalyseTabContent : Grid, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
... 
public MapAnalyseTabContent()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        AnalysisViewModel = new analysisViewModel ();
        binsColorsCtrl.DataContext = AnalysisViewModel;

        ...
    }
```

...
   }

with its xaml side:

```
<Grid 
   xmlns:CustomControl="clr-namespace:MyApp.CustomControl"
   ...>
    ...
    <CustomControl:BinsColorControl x:Name="binsColorsCtrl" BinsColors="{Binding BinsColors}" BinsValues="{Binding BinsValues}"/>
</Grid>
```

here is the xaml code for the custom view

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApp.CustomControl.BinsColorControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp.CustomControl"
         xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" Width="139.423">
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <xctk:IntegerUpDown x:Name="NOBinsControl" Value="{Binding NOBins}" Margin="4,10,4,10" ></xctk:IntegerUpDown>
    <StackPanel  x:Name="binStack" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <xctk:ColorPicker x:Name="colorPick1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="4,2,4,2"/>
    <xctk:DoubleUpDown x:Name="doubleSpin_bin1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="4,2,4,2"/>
    <xctk:ColorPicker x:Name="colorPick2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="4,2,4,2"/>
        <xctk:DoubleUpDown x:Name="doubleSpin_bin2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="4,2,4,2"/>
        <xctk:ColorPicker x:Name="colorPick3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="4,2,4,2"/>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: You should learn to use Bindings in your XAML; I doubt that anything in `_reloadUI()` here is actually needed. *"could not understand how they would get individual items of the collection."* -- please clarify; a collection is a collection is a collection. You need to understand that we can't see the code you're thinking about. We can only see the words you type in your question.

Comment: Yep. Are your dependency properties in the view or viewmodel. Usually dp would be in view and the viewmodel is a plain class implementing inotifypropertychanged. Observablecollections notify on remove add or update of their items. And.... I can only guess where the collection comes in. Maybe the spin thing cycles through colours. But then somehow there's a bins colorcontrol. What?

Comment: Yes I will put all the code and the viewmodel